# Insert HTML data to SQL Server

Tags: html, asp.net, sql-server, tags

I'd like to insert HTML data in SQL Server using ASP.NET and a stored procedure but I'm not able to insert all the tags and double quotes. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You would have to escape double quotes while entering your data so can you try something like this? `"Hyey there, \"How are you?\""`

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You should check out "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You can use base64 encoding to store and decoding when reading the data

Comment: Why should you escape characters in SQL-Server as base64? You only need to do this, when you cannot handle the whole characterset.

Answer (score 0):

First try to strip down your problem to the basics:

1. SQL-Server has a datetype nvarchar(max). This typ can store a lot of data. All characters that "arive" at the database can be inserted. You shoul first check, what data arives at the server. An easy way is SQL prifiler. You should see the data in Profiler, that "arives" at the database. If things are broken here (i.e.wrong encoding) you should the way up to you application.
2. Which way comes the data? You only mention ASP.NET. You can connect to the database using ODBC, JDBC, OLEDB or ADO-driver (there might be more). Data can be converterd on this way. You can set up a Trace an see what happens. The easy way normaly is the fastest: Check the options of the driver/try other settings. Most drivers have only a small number of options. If you can not find the problem here...
3. Your application. Strip it down to the minimal functionality: Establish a connection to the database an insert some data into a table. Does this work? Does it work with different collation? Does it word with unicode data?

Maybe a better question could better be answered.